# ASP.NET MVC 5 ExternalLogin() method failing to execute for Google OAuth; works fine for Facebook

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth, google-oauth

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5's baked-in OAuth code to allow users to configure membership using their Google or Facebook credentials, the desired behavior being that once the access token is passed, the user is redirected to the application homepage via `Home{Controller}\Index{action}`. In regards to Google, I'm having trouble with the execution flow, even though it shares the exact same logic as Facebook, which works like a charm (see below):

**1. User clicks login button:**

```
 using (Html.BeginForm("ExternalLogin", "Account", new {ReturnUrl = Model.ReturnUrl}))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="social_sign">
            @foreach (AuthenticationDescription p in loginProviders)
            {
                <button class="@p.Caption"
                        id="@p.AuthenticationType"
                        name="provider"
                        title="Log in using your @p.Caption account"
                        type="submit"
                        value="@p.AuthenticationType">
                    <i class="fa fa-@p.Caption" style="color: #ffffff"></i>
                </button>
            }
        </div>
    }
```

**2. `ExternalLogin()` Method is called:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)
    {
        return new ChallengeResult(provider, Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "Account", new {ReturnUrl = returnUrl}));
    }
```

**3. `ExternalLoginCallback()` method is invoked:**

```
  [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
    {
        var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (loginInfo == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }

        // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login
        var result = await SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo, isPersistent: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = false });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                // If the user does not have an account, then prompt the user to create an account
                ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
                ViewBag.LoginProvider = loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider;
                return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", new ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel { Email = loginInfo.Email });
        }
    }
```

**4. `Login()` method is invoked:**

```
    // GET: /Account/Login
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }
```

However, when a user clicks the Google button, the `ExternalLogin()` method is called and then execution stops (i.e. the app tries to return a nonexistent `Account/ExternalLogin` view), but rather than load a `Resource not found` error, the page load just times out in Chrome. Setting a breakpoint at `return new ChallengeResult()` within the method showed that it wasn't being executed. I am failing to see how this could happen since I can't reproduce the error using the exact same logic with a different login provider. I'm new to working with ASP.NET MVC's OAuth configuration.

Code in `StartupAuth.cshtml` looks fine too:

```
  app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
           appId: ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FacebookId"],
           appSecret: ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FacebookSecret"]);

        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
        {
            ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GoogleId"],
            ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GoogleSecret"],
        });
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you show us some error message? Have you enabled Google+ API?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that no error is being returned; the page load merely times out. See edit above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common cause for AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync() to return null is that the Google+ API is not enabled in the google developers console. It is not enabled by default, which can be misleading when you are first experimenting with the external login providers included with the MVC5 template.

To check if it is enabled, go to https://console.developers.google.com and choose the project you have created.

Navigate to APIs, and look for Google+ under the Social Media API section. If you see a button to Enable API, then the Google+ API is disabled for this application, and clicking enable should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the "remove" line below in Web.config did it for me.

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
  </modules>
<system.webServer>
```